Ubuntu 22.04.05 randomy freezing, hard reboot required
I recently upgraded Ubuntu on my laptop to 22.04.5. No errors were reported. After the upgrade, my laptop randomly freezes. Sound keeps working, but otherwise the keyboard, screen and mouse/trackpad are unresponsive. The only way out is a hard reboot. Some searching led me to believe the problem is the "nouveau" graphics driver. When I tried to install a Nvidia driver as alternative, the installation process failed. I followed the instructions by "furkanzdm" here:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/errors-were-encountered-while-processing-dkms/236521/14
to manually purge Nvidia packages and then re-install "nvidia-driver-550", run update-initramfs and reboot.
Then I attempted to switch to using the Nvidia driver by
prime-select nvidia
Even though no errors were reported during the purging/installation, the problem persists. Sometimes one minute in, sometimes a few hours, I need to hard reboot - completely unworkable.
I am not an expert and would greatly appreciate some help with determining the root cause and making sure that I have the correct Nvidia driver and it is actually being used (assuming that "nouveau" is indeed the problem).
I have since found a number of similar questions but none seem to have definitive answers. If possible, I would like to avoid installing software from repos other than the official Ubuntu channels (as suggested here System freezes randomly without explicit errors @ Ubuntu 22.04 LTS).
My system is a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 6; 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz × 8; Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2); GNOME version 42.9; Windowing System Wayland. "proprietary drivers for devices" is enabled.

Just in case it helps, I had boot issues in 22.04 when I switched from hand-installing Nvidia drivers to using the Ubuntu bundled ones, and things got better when I followed these instructions: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation, in particular using sudo ubuntu-drivers install. Not sure if that does anything that you're missing out, but see what you think.

Thanks, that is a useful page. Unfortunately, I fail in the first step. When executing "sudo ubuntu-drivers list" I see:

oem-sutton.newell-aekerley-meta
and that is all. Nothing like the example on that page and no mention of Nvidia. When I try "sudo ubuntu-drivers install" I get:
All the available drivers are already installed.
I do not understand this. On Synaptic I see nvidia-driver-550 is installed, but the system doesn't seem to use or see it at all.


Does Ubuntu still freeze when running an Ubuntu live session from a bootable Ubuntu USB?

By given specs you don't have any nvidia GPU, so install nvidia drivers will only cause problems. The driver your want are called mesa, the mesa driver are already in your system and don't need manual intervention in any case.
*only install iris xe for data centers CPU's require the driver be manually installed
Your GPU driver are already in kernel since version 5.10
https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/devices/hardware-table.html

Well, that would explain a lot. Is "mesa" an alternative to "nouveau"? If so, how do I switch from one to the other. If not, what could be causing the crashes? I assumed "nouveau" was the culprit based on a number of similar descriptions of crashes I found on the forms..
